# Can't understand the buffer overflow example in "The Art of Exploitation"

Tags: security, buffer-overflow, exploit, shellcode

My problem is very similar but not the same with the [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696517/buffer-overflow-example-from-art-of-exploitation-book).

I run the same example of exploit_notesearch.c in the book: Hacking, the Art of Exploitation on my 64-bit OS, Archlinux and it doesn't work.

From the above link I learnt that it just can't work on most 64-bit systems. But I still can't understand why the programme have to do this: `ret = (unsigned int)&i - offset`. Why can't I just do this: `ret = (unsigned)shellcode` so that I can replace the vulnerable program's return address with shellcode's beginning address?

Comment: `&i - offset` is used in linked question ("this one") to get address of `buffer` (variable stored on ... Wat? on heap), not of `shellcode` (static variable).

Comment: But I found in gdb that the address buffer pointed to is much smaller than &i(Should heap address be much smaller than stack address if not much memory is used?). But the example set offset to 270, that I think it assume these two address is close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ret = (unsigned)shellcode` will make the `ret` equals to the address of the shellcode array in your program. But that address is not the address of your malicious code in the target program(`notesearch.c`). The target process will put its `searchstring` on stack, so that your malicious code will be also put onto the stack of the target process.

In old days, the memory layout of processes was typically highly deterministic - the location of the stack buffer could usually be predicted quite well by the attacker (particularly if they knew exactly which version of the target software was being attacked). So it will be very easy to know what is the exact address of the `searchstring` and your shellcode.

However, today, many operating system will perform ASLR. So attackers trying to execute shellcode injected on the stack have to find the stack first. The system obscures related memory-addresses from the attackers. These values have to be guessed, and a mistaken guess is not usually recoverable due to the application crashing(Segmentation Fault).

To improve the chances of success when there was some guesswork involved, the active shellcode would often be preceeded by a large quantity of executable machine code that performed no useful operation - called a "NOP sled" or "NOP slide".

So even the `ret = (unsigned int)&i - offset` can not make sure your shellcode will be executed succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

Also, do this if you're stuck trying to get the exploit to work:

1. Make sure you compile and create booksrc/notetaker and booksrc/notesearch
2. Set the permissions for each file.  This includes making sure the appropriate file is root and suid-set as well;
3. Once done, create a note within notetaker to match the progress of the book up to this point.
4. Test the notesearch functionality (as a standard user) just to make sure that the program works

Many people (including myself) assumed it would just WORK but the book assumes you're following the progress to a T. This includes allowing the application to search for specific notes that *should* exist up to this point...even if you...take breaks...like I did, LOL

Hope this helps anyone stucc (yes, stucc)