# buffer overflow exploit example from "Hacking: The Art of Exploitation"

Tags: security, buffer-overflow, exploit, shellcode

I've found a few related posts about this on the site but non of them explained my problem.
The code is described here:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696517/buffer-overflow-example-from-art-of-exploitation-book)

My issue is the following:

The author tries to rewrite the return address of the strcpy() function in the notesearch.c program with one in the buffer so that the shellcode (which I understand is implanted machine code in the memory) will be executed.

For that to work he creates a buffer that looks like: nop nop nop ... | shell code .. | return address

From what I understand after the call to the strcpy() function the buffer is put on the stack and overwrites the return value to notesearch.c's main. He does that so when the strcpy() finishes running and wants to return to the main he'll call the return value from the buffer.

What I don't understand are the following:

1. It seems to me like the injected return address is always perfectly aligned with the original. How can that be?
2. It said in the book that the injected return address points to the shellcode in the same buffer. Why would we want to put the shellcode in the same buffer and not in another part of the memory? Couldn't that cause an infinite loop?
3. Why can't we set the return address to that of the shellcode on the buffer? Or to the variable shellcode for that matter?
4. Can anyone elaborate on how the return address was calculated and why we need the offset?

Answer (score 0):

**Why would we want to put the shellcode in the same buffer and not in another part of the memory?**

Well you are actually free to place the shellcode wherever you want as long as you can execute instructions in that memory region. That being said, this example demonstrate a stack based buffer overflow, in such exploits it's pretty easy to discover the offset of a local variable inside the current stack frame.

**Couldn't that cause an infinite loop?**

Assuming the shellcode doesn't contains a such infinite loop - no. Yet that might produce bugs since you are modifying the execution flow. This really depends of the shellcode. For instance most shellcode are used to spawn a shell - let's assume the exec function family is used - so once the shell spawns the original executable image will be overridden by the shell.

**Why can't we set the return address to that of the shellcode on the buffer?**

You can, this only require a more precise calculation. Using the NOP sled you have multiple possible hit that will enable your shellcode execution.

**Can anyone elaborate on how the return address was calculated?**

The author took the address of the first declared local variable and computed the displacement to the vulnerable buffer. The first drawback here is that the first declared variable (**i**) might not be the first local variable once compiled. If you want to ensure such constraint a workaround is to use a struct (See: [Order of local variable allocation on the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1102165/1006834)).

The author probably ran the program multiple times and adjusted the offset until the shellcode gets triggered. Keep in mind that computing the exact address of the buffer is really platform and compiler dependent. You will have to debug your program and inspect how the compiler elaborates stack frame etc.

**Why we need the offset?**

Because of the stack frame layout a "valid" offset is required to find an address who will hits the NOP sled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a layman so this will be placed in layman terms:

I figured this out after banging my head against each letter of the book - Check this out:
Remember this quote from page 139 of HTAOE:

> "Now the buffer contains the desired shellcode and is long enough to overwrite the return address. The difficulty of finding the exact location of the
> return address is eased by using the repeated return address technique. But
> this return address must point to the shellcode located in the same buffer."

This subtle line tells us that the purpose of the return address is to get the execution to flow directly to the shellcode.

THIS is why we create so many copies.  Think of it as an execution 'net' to drive all of the execution to a single point.  Ideally that single point is the shell code, however, due to compiler optimizations, the architecture, and other things, the chances of you reaching that specific address are very...VERY slim...

This is where the NO-Operations (aka NOPs) (AKA 0x90's) come in.  Imagine being able to return the execution to a place that we KNOW will eventually, and unconditionally reach our shellcode...This is the purpose of a NOP slide.

NOTE: Now please note:  By this point within the book, we don't know anything about if this particular return address (variable is named as 'ret') is the one we're looking for.  Later on (like a page later), the book tells you that you can experiment with the 'offset' variable.

This is why exploit_notesearch.c's *offset* variable attributed with argv[1].  The idea is to play with different offsets to see where in your machine's memory the return address of the soon-to-be executed program will be located.

This may lead you to a question:

1. Won't the filling up of buffer and blind-loading it into memory cause you to overflow the entire stack frame of the other program? (Main, and the other frames?)?

Great Question - I had that same question until I started going back and forth!

Answer: NO! As you'll recall from page 137 (at the top), they mention that THIS is the vulnerable line item:
strcpy(searchstring, argv[1]); // that is the search string;

What makes this vulnerable is that it copies unsanitized user data directly into memory which can be anything from 'a user generated password' to 'a highly specific crafted exploit designed to grant ROOT on a given device' (and everything in between! :D).

When you think about it, notesearch's argv[1] is in fact *JUST A POINTER TO SOME DATA* and is not yet directly used in execution.  It's only when we jump into the print_notes function (using that dangerous string as an argument), we start to see the effects of not sanitizing your input.  (Note search's source code is on page 93 and 94 of HTAOE)

So to answer, and wrap things up, how this should go is as follows (paraphrasing of course because Im a layman myself):

1. exploit_notesearch.c crafts shellcode;
2. We create a space in memory (heap, but that's not important) that we plan to use later
3. We copy the string: (./notesearch ') into the the space in memory created in step 2
4. We point a pointer to the address allocated *AFTER* (yes AFTER) the command created in step 2 (e.g. after ./notesearch ')
5. **Does some fancy arithmetic to get SOME VALUE located in a stack frame located AFTER the stack frame that houses the variable 'i' [In other words, we use I to reference the stack frame for the next running program in memory...](Remember that this is STILL an EXPERIMENTAL VALUE --> Play with it! ;D ) ALSO NOTE: This step does some typecasting to convert the value to an unsigned integer
6. Starting at the buffer address (located AFTER the command created in step 2), we use a for loop to start stacking 4 byte EXPERIMENTAL return addresses
   into the space allocated in step 2 (but AFTER the ./notesearch command!). (Note: we have to use some MORE fancy typecasting to be able to treat it as if it was an address again).
7. This is where we copy the NOP sled into the buffer but not filling it completely.  Note here that we only copy the first 60 bytes (memset(buffer, 0x90, 60)) the syntax being: (memset(where you wanna copy something, what you wanna copy, how many copies of your copy do you wanna copy?).
8. Now we place the shellcode AFTER the NO-OP slides...hopefully you can see this coming together, but if not, I'll give a baby summary below
9. Finally, we add the shellcode schmak dab in the middle of the no-op slides and the return address.  Here's what it should look like as a command:
   ./notesearch '[NOP][NOP][NOP][NOP]...[Shellcode]...[ReturnAddy][ReturnAddy][ReturnAddy]...'

Lastly, if all goes well, here's what I think we should see (assuming the offset is coorect):

The above numbers happen >> This program Executes notesearch with a dirty argument (including shellcode, buffer, nops, the works) >> The program execution starts (main stack frame is created) >> We copy that 'dirty argument' into some variable >> That variable is used as an argument in *someOtherFunction* where it's contents OVERWRITE THE RETURN ADDRESS INTO the nop-slide (e.g. because we got that offset value correct).  >> Execution slides down the nops and we wake up with root!

If the offset value was NOT correct, we would still overwrite the return value, but with an incorrect address that would return execution to...well...some other section of memory - a section that'd cause chaos at worst and a segfault at best...

I spent a few days (a wannabe reverser with no practical experience) going BACK and FORTH between page 90something and 140 till I got it!
It was kinda frustrating the way the book sorta just lightly touched on these points but I'm JUST at the end of the chapter, and feel like I can finally move on after making that discovery.